# Discretisize Pandas' column given the data distribution

Tags: python, performance, pandas, numpy

I have a pandas' dataframe with one column that holds real data ranging from 0 to 50. They are not evenly distributed.

I can get the distribution using:

```
hist, bins = np.histogram(df["col"])
```

What I would like to do is to replace every value with the bins' number it falls in.

To do so, this was working:

```
for i in range(len(df["speed_array"])):
    df["speed_array"].iloc[i] = np.searchsorted(bins, df["speed_array"].iloc[i])
```

However, with an dataframe with more the 4 millions of row, it is quite slow (50 minutes). I am searching for a more efficient way to this. Do you guys have a better idea ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simply use [`np.searchsorted`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.searchsorted.html) on the entire underlying array data -

```
df["speed_array"] = np.searchsorted(bins, df["speed_array"].values)
```

Runtime test -

```
In [140]: # 4 million rows with 100 bins
     ...: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randint(0,1000,(4000000,1)))
     ...: df.columns = [['speed_array']]
     ...: bins = np.sort(np.random.choice(1000, size=100, replace=0))
     ...: 

In [141]: def searchsorted_app(df):
     ...:     df["speed_array"] = np.searchsorted(bins, df["speed_array"].values)
     ...:     

In [142]: %timeit searchsorted_app(df)
10 loops, best of 3: 15.3 ms per loop
```

Comment: As simple as I was dreaming about! Thanks!

Comment: @Xema Would be nice to know the speedup over the original `50min` mark :)

Comment: Well, it was pretty much instant!